# sendgrid getting error : The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

when i try to send email with `From Name : xxx@gmail.com` it is not working, i am getting this error : `The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity` , can anyone please help me how to verify gmail domain ? so i can send email from gmail also, here is my code for it

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("xxxx@gmail.com", "test");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("xxxx@gmail.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);

$apiKey = 'xxxxxxx';

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($response); 
    exit;
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

Comment: After loging into your sendgrid account, goto https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth/senders .Click "Create new sender" Then put the `from` email address that you want use to send mails in "From Email Address" and "Reply To" fields and fill out other details. After adding this, you will receive a verification mail. Verify it. After this you will be able to use the provided email address in `from` while sending mail.